# How to reference to a cell of an array inside of an array in Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift, reference

I'm somewhat of a noobie in Swift. I have an array of arrays. I would like to reference to letter `"H"` i.e. to the first cell of the first array using only one line of code. How is this done in Swift? I.e. how do I write the last two lines of example code in one line and without using `temp`?

```
   let textArrays = [
                        ["H","E","L","L","O"],
                        ["W","O","R","L","D","!"]
                    ]
    let temp = textArrays[0]
    let HWLabel.text = HWLabel.text + temp[0].description
```

Comment: `textArrays[0][0]`

Comment: I should have guessed. I was trying `textArrays[0].[0]` Thank you!

Comment: @Sweeper do you mind writing your comment as an answer so I could accept the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *two way to access 2D array's element*
**1.**  is :-

```
let arr = [[ "1", "2", "3"], ["A", "B", "C"]]

let arrOne = arr[0]  // will behave like [ "1", "2", "3"]
let X = arrOne[1]  // will have "1"

let arrTwo = arr[1]  // will behave like ["A", "B", "C"]
let D = arrTwo[2]  // will have "C"
```

**2.** Short version is

```
`print(array[0][1], array[1][2])`  // will print "1 C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing one dimension of an array is like this:

```
textArrays[0]
```

Since this is a 2D array, doing the above will give you another array. To access an index in *that* array, add `[x]` again!

```
textArrays[0][0]
```

You can also do the same for a 3D array:

```
some3DArray[0][0][0]
```